# Android notification, vibrates but no sound

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I've read some of the other posts on this subject and I think my code should be sounding
an alarm, but it's not. It does vibrate, but no sound.  Any suggestions on how to get
this to convey sound ?

Another part of the program is able to play a ringtone so the problem seems to be 
specific this routine.

This is in a class that extends Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    if (sound == null) { Log.i("RECEIVER", "SOUND IS NULL"); }

    NotificationManager myNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intentMain = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentMain, 0);

    long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};

    Notification myNote = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("NotificationDemo")
            .setContentText("NotificatinDemo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();

    myNM.notify(1, myNote);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, guys. Neither of these worked. I'm still just getting the vibrate. Do I need to set anything in the apps manifest ?

Comment: Just a guess: Try calling `super.onStartCommand()` before posting the notification. Maybe you need that to initialize the service first.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("NotificationDemo")
                .setContentText("NotificatinDemo")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent);

Notification myNote = mBuilder.build();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    myNote.sound = sound;
    myNote.category = Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM;

    AudioAttributes.Builder attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
    attrs.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION);
    attrs.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM);
    myNote.audioAttributes = attrs.build();
} else  {
    mBuilder.setSound(sound, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    myNote = mBuilder.build();
}

myNM.notify(1, myNote);
```

Also check these: [Lollipop notification feature](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/lollipop.html#Notifications), [`AudioAttributes` class used in new notification system](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html), and [usage of Audio Attributes](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes.html).

Answer (score 0):

First Check your device notification sound settings.

Then try this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(someText)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: Hi Vijay. Thanks for the suggestion. I checked my phone's default notification sound and it is set to a non 'none' value. Even with your suggested code changes I'm still not getting any sound, just the vibrate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Notification myNote = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("NotificationDemo")
            .setContentText("NotificatinDemo")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();
```