# Alarm doesn't ring in silent/priority mode

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, alarmmanager, android-alarms

The following piece of code is supposed to ring while on silent/priority mode in Android 5+, but I've found out it actually doesn't ring if such was set hours before the deadline. However, the notification it-self appears correctly, but muted. Does anyone know a way to achieve that, or maybe a workaround? Thanks in advance.

```
var alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Activity.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
var intent = new Intent (Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast (Context, 0, intent,
    PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
// milliseconds is a double containing those from now to the alarm time
alarmManager.SetExact (AlarmType.RtcWakeup, milliseconds, pendingIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
var notificationIntent = new Intent (context, typeof(MyActivity));
var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (context, 0, notificationIntent,
    PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
var manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From (context);
var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder (context)
    .SetContentIntent (contentIntent)
    .SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis())
    // Yes, I'm using a custom sound (MP3)
    .SetSound(soundUri)
    .SetCategory(Notification.CategoryAlarm)
    .Build();

manager.Notify(0, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329004/android-notification-vibrates-but-no-sound) will help.

Try adding a priority to the notification and then add an AudioAttributes object as the second parameter of setSound. I think the system is playing your sound on an audio stream which has been muted. From the question linked:

```
AudioAttributes.Builder attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
attrs.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION);
attrs.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM);

notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
notification.setSound(soundUri, attrs.build());
```

Edit:
Note that if the device has Do Not Disturb completely on (Total Silence), the system will not play your notification sound regardless of what attributes you set here.

Comment: Thanks mate, I finally made it work through a workaround, which's showing an Activity on top of the blocked screen, where I then play the MP3.